# git report moved lines

Tags: bash, git

I want to track the number of additions and deletions that ***exclude*** moved lines.  So if a commit has 10 additions, 5 deletions, and 3 moved lines, then I have 7 additions, 2 deletions excluding moved lines.  The 10 and 5 are given by the following code.  I need to generate the 3 (I only need weak moved line detection, e.g. any line that appears identically as simultaneously deleted from one location and added to another location within the same commit).

I am using the following to track number of additions and deletions for an important file in my git repository.

```
git log --since=2014-08-01 --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad%x09" --numstat -- file.tex
```

This yields the following, where the first number is additions and the second number is deletions.

```
2014-08-19      
72      0       file.tex

2014-08-19      
211     290     file.tex

...
```

I want to add a third column, call it moved lines.  The moved lines per commit can be found by doing the following in a loop for every commit:

1. Grep changeset for lines starting with + or -
2. Strip leading + or -
3. `sort`
4. `uniq -d`
5. `wc -l`

Is there an fast and elegant way to run this pseudocode or do I just need to dump and parse a bunch of full git diffs to get what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following implementation in the [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) language. At first, I used your algorithm for determining the moved count. However, I noticed that it produces results which are not useful: for instance it was identifying positive values for "moved lines" in changes that contained nothing but `+` lines, simply because some of the `+` lines were duplicates of each other. The new algorithm is discussed in Notes at the end.

The complete program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env txr
@(bind option-spec
       @(list (opt nil "since" :str
                   "Specifies the starting date (passed \
                   \ through to git); it is mandatory.")
              (opt nil "help" :bool
                   "Prints this help text")))
@(bind parsed-opts @(getopts option-spec *args*))
@(if (or [parsed-opts "help"] (not [parsed-opts "since"])))
@  (output)

usage: @{self-path} --since=<date> -- git arguments
@  (end)
@  (do (opthelp option-spec)
       (exit 0))
@(end)
@(do
   (defun histogram (strings)
     [group-reduce (hash :equal-based) identity (op succ @1) strings 0])

   (defun moved (a b)
     (let* ((hist-a (histogram a))
            (hist-b (histogram b))
            (isec [hash-isec hist-a hist-b min]))
       [reduce-left + (hash-values isec) 0])))
@(next (open-command `git log --since=@[parsed-opts "since"] \
                     \ --date=short --pretty=format:"%H:%ad%x09" \
                     \ --numstat @{parsed-opts.out-args}`))
@(repeat)
@sha:@date@\t
@  (collect :gap 0)
@added@\t@removed@\t@rawpath
@    (next :string rawpath)
@    (cases)
@pro/{@before => @after}/@epi
@      (bind path `@pro/@after/@epi`)
@    (or)
@before => @after
@      (bind path after)
@    (or)
@      (bind path rawpath)
@    (end)
@    (next (open-command `git show -p @sha -- @path`))
@    (collect :vars ((+line nil) (-line nil)))
@      (cases)
+@{+line}
@      (or)
-@{-line}
@      (end)
@    (end)
@    (flatten -line +line)
@    (bind moved @(moved +line -line))
@  (end)
@  (output)
@date@\t
@    (repeat)
@added@\t@removed@\t@moved@\t@rawpath
@    (end)

@  (end)
@(end)
```

I have this in a marked executable file called `movedlines.txr` and example usage is:

```
$ ./movedlines.txr --since=2017-01-01 path/to
```

The `--since` option is mandatory; the `path/to` is an optional argument passed through to `git`. If you don't specify the mandatory option, or you specify `--help`, then the program prints a help summary and quits.

Notes:

- I changed the output format of your example `git` command slightly to include the SHA to the left of the date, separated by a colon: see the `%H`. The program parses that out and then it can use the SHA to do a `git show -p` on each file in each set.  The SHA is omitted when the imitation of the output is regurgitated by the program with the additional moved column.
- There is a complication in that the output of git shows renames. The syntax falls into three cases, which are clearly and easily parsed by cases using the `@(cases)` construct.  If an entire path is renamed, the rename is `from => to`. If just some components are renamed, it is `be/fore/{from => to}/after`. I don't know if multiple curly brace syntax occurs in one path; I haven't seen it. We must munge this syntax and convert it to a plain path, because git doesn't understand it. I.e. we must convert `be/fore/{from => to}/after` into `be/fore/to/after`.  Maybe there is a git option to have the paths output that way without the notation; I didn't bother looking.
- The script is not robust robust against spaces in filenames because of the use of `open-command`. For that we need `open-process` which takes an argument list.
- The algorithm calculates separate frequency histograms of the diff `-` and 
  `+` lines (minus their leading `-` or `+`). Then it calculates the intersection of these sets, which keeps only those histogram entries which occur in both histograms. The join function for the intersection is `min`. So for instance suppose line `abc` was added 5 times and removed 3 times. `(min 3 5)` is `3` and that's the number of moved `abc` lines. This commutes. If 3 occurrences of `abc` are removed, and 5 added, that implies 3 moves. This is by no means posited as some sort of perfect algorithm for detecting moves. It has obvious pitfalls like not detecting lines which *de facto* move but also undergo a trivial whitespace change, like indentation.